AWS Appflow Custom Connector for SharePoint - Filtering fields issue
I am trying to create a generic connector for SharePoint to S3 via Appflow custom connector. Since its a workplace work, I cannot share the code.
I found out that SharePoint only allows -
File Type & Last Modified DateTime as filters
I want other metadata fields to be used as Filters too.
The problem is I have applied those filters in code and its showing the "Appflow-Filters" Tab part,
like along with the above 2 filters i tried with Name and Size but its not filtering the files as required, how do I make them functionally working.

